# How can I name a table with a string or var?

Tags: python, sqlite, discord.py

I want to program a Discord bot which creates a table with some simple input. Therefore I  need to know how I can name the table in sqlite  like  my variable, `Splitdata`.

My code:

```py
if message.content.startswith(PREFIX + "create"):
    data = message.content
    Spliteddata = data.split()
    await message.reply(Spliteddata[1])
    Test = """CREATE TABLE Splitteddata[1] (vorname VARCHAR(20), nachname VARCHAR(30), geburtstag DATE)"""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert variables into strings like this :

```
age = 22
a_string = f"My name is {age}"
```

So your example would become

```
Test = f"""CREATE TABLE {Splitteddata[1]} (vorname VARCHAR(20), nachname VARCHAR(30), geburtstag DATE)"""
```

Simply add the f at the beginning of the string, and you can use { and } so that anything in between will not be considered a string
It's called f-strings https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/formatted-string-literals-f-strings-python/